# Handling wildcards in linux shell script

Tags: command-line

I have a directory named "directoryname". If i give the command: cd direc* it will go straight into that folder and that's fine. What I want to do is, get the name of the directory from this. As i am running this inside an script, I want to get the full name that the command automatically selected on it's own after this operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ${PWD##*/}
```

Go this from this post in the past:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script

if you want the full path then just:

```
pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the result of wildcard expansion with:

```
echo direc*
```

Save it into variable:

```
var=$(echo direc*)
```

Comment: using `*.*` can be an applicable one as well.\